# What does רעך בתורה ובמצוות mean?

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, love, contemporary-halacha

The Torah says [וְאָהַבְתָּ לְרֵעֲךָ כָּמוֹךָ](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.19.18?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&with=Commentary&lang2=en), Love your fellow as yourself.

Actual *halacha*:

[Kitzur Shulchan Aruch](https://www.sefaria.org/Kitzur_Shulchan_Aruch.29.12?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):
It is incumbent upon every Jew to love every fellow Jew as he loves himself.

[Rambam](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Human_Dispositions.6.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):
It is mandatory upon every man to love each and every one of Israel even as he loves his own self.

However, the *[Sefer Mitzvot Gadol](https://www.sefaria.org/Sefer_Mitzvot_Gadol%2C_Positive_Commandments.9.1?vhe=Munkatch,_1901&lang=en&with=all&lang2=en)* says ודווקא לרעך שהוא רעך בתורה ובמצות אבל אדם רשע ואינו מקבל תוכחה מצוה לשנאותו, specifically your fellow (Jew) that he is your fellow in Torah and mitzvos. But if he is wicked and doesn't accept rebuke it is a mitzvah to hate him.

In addition, we also find the [verse](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.19.15?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=bi) בְּצֶדֶק תִּשְׁפֹּט עֲמִיתֶךָ, judge your kinsman fairly, to which the *[Gemara](https://www.sefaria.org/Shevuot.30a.13?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)* derives עם שאתך בתורה ובמצות, With regard to one who is with you [*im she’itekha*] in observance of Torah and in fulfillment of mitzvot.

In *halacha*, which positive or negative commandments in the Torah would disqualify someone from being in the category of רעך בתורה ובמצות?

Comment: Does the mitzvah apply to all Jews? Based on the sources you provided, it would appear so.

Comment: The 2nd answer in the Q that @DonielF mentioned answers your question, here. Thus, I'm also voting to close as a duplicate.

Comment: I don't see how this question is a duplicate at all. This question is about wicked Jews, the other is about non-Jews

Answer (score 1):

[Rav Avigdor Miller on Loving Jews](https://torasavigdor.org/rav-avigdor-miller-on-loving-jews/)

"Now, first of all, I want to tell you that it’s not necessary to love all Jews. Only the shomrei mitzvos. On the non-shomrei mitzvos there is no chiyuv. ואהבת לרעך כמוך – “You should love your fellow.” So the gemara explains it means רעך במצוות – your fellow in doing mitzvos. If it is a fellow Jew, a rei’acha b’mitzvos, then you have a chiyuv di’oraisa to learn to love him."

Comment: I saw this before. They didn’t mention the Gemara that he quoted.

Comment: @ChiddusheiTorah See the comment in Hagahos Maimoniyos on the Rambam you cited (De'os 3:6) "ודוקא שהוא רעך בתורה ובמצות, אבל אדם רשע שאינו מקבל תוכחה מצוה לשנאתו שנאמר (משלי ח יג) "יראת ה' שנאת רע", ואומר (תהלים קלט כא) "הלא משנאיך ה' אשנא" וגו'. עכ"ל.

Comment: Can you provide me with a hyperlink?

Comment: @ChiddusheiTorah     Hagahos Maimoniyos on the Rambam you cited (De'os 6:3, note 1) http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=1&rtype=%u05E6%u05D5%u05E8%u05EA%20%u05D4%u05D3%u05E3&hilchos=2&perek=6&halocha=3